# Android GridView with Label from JSON Response

Tags: android, json, gridview, label

Anyone know how to get the GridView, by loading the images and labels from the JSON that has the imageurls and labels. I 've done Image loading part, but every time I open the page, it duplicates the images and finding difficulties in setting the labels. Please let me know a way to solve this.below is adapter code

```
public class ImageAdapterGrid extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter{
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapterGrid(Context c){
    super();
    this.mContext = c;
    SymGridConfig.addImageUrls();        
}

  public int getCount() {
   return SymGridConfig.getUrl_list().size();

 }

public Object getItem(int position) {
   return SymGridConfig.getUrl_list().get(position);
 }

public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {      

   View view = convertView;
   ImageView imageView;
   if(convertView==null)
   {

       imageView=new ImageView(mContext);
       imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180,180));
       imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
       imageView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
   }else{
       imageView=(ImageView)convertView;

   }
   imageView.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromURL(SymGridConfig.
                            getUrl_list().get(position)));       
   return imageView;

 }

  private Drawable LoadImageFromURL(String url)
   {
   try
   {
   InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
   Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
   return d;
   }catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
   return null;
   }
   }
   }
```

and class SymGridConfig as follows:

```
public class SymGridConfig {


 private static String url = "http://192.168.0.6/tele_medicine/index.php/symptoms/list";  

   private static final String SYMP_ID = "symp_id";
   private static final String SYMP_NAME = "symptom_name";
   private static final String SYMP_LOGO_URL = "symptom_logo";

  static ArrayList<String> url_list=new ArrayList<String>();
  static ArrayList<String> title_list = new ArrayList<String>();
  static ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();

  public static ArrayList<Item> getGridArray(){
    return gridArray;

  }
  public static void setGridArray(ArrayList<Item> gridArray)
  {
      SymGridConfig.gridArray = gridArray;
  }

   public static ArrayList<String> getUrl_list() {
       return url_list;
    }

   public static void setUrl_list(ArrayList<String> url_list) {
       SymGridConfig.url_list = url_list;
    }

  public static ArrayList<String> getTitles(){
        return title_list;
    }

   public static void setTitle_list(ArrayList<String> url_list) {
       SymGridConfig.url_list = url_list;
    }

   public static void addImageUrls(){   
     ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

       // Making a request to url and getting response
       String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(img_url, ServiceHandler.GET);

       if (jsonStr != null) {
           try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   String diag_id = jsonObject.getString(SYMP_ID);   
                   String diag_name = jsonObject.getString(SYMP_NAME);
                   String img_url = jsonObject.getString(SYMP_LOGO_URL);
                   String logo_url="http://m2mapps.co.in/images/symptoms/";                        
                   img_url = logo_url.concat(img_url);
                   title_list.add(diag_name);
                   url_list.add(img_url);
                   gridArray.add(new Item(img_url,diag_name));

               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       } else {
           Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
       }    
  }
  }
```

the above code loads the image and duplicates whenever I reopen the page and facing trouble at setting labels for the images. The label should be symptom_name.

Comment: just post your code here, be specific please

Comment: The issue of duplicate images is probably due to not clearing the collection `Collection.clear();` check this in your adapter code

Comment: Post you code Please!

Comment: Finally I got it done